Phantom Wallet Recovery
i just register wallet at the first July 2024 , and i didnt save the secert recovery phrase , i have link the account game Backwood with my Twitter and Discord , i still use this mac address , your guys can check it , sorry for my fault I didn't save that Secret Recovery Phrase, can your guys help me please

Do you have access to your private key? I'm sorry if you've lost your secret phrase, but nothing can be done. Flagging this to be closed as I think this question doesn't belong in the scope of topics for this stack exchange.
